# Capturing two sub-strings in a regex search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

```
string  = "First Name: John Last Name: Doe"
string2 = "First Name: John Last Name: Doe de Sour"
regex   = (First Name|Last Name): ([A-Za-z]+)
```

How can I modify my regex to also include "de Sour"?  If I add a space like so:

```
regex   = (First Name|Last Name): ([A-Za-z ]+)
```

Then it'll capture "Last Name" as well.  The string is derived from the body contents of an email, so it's important that I search for First Name and Last Name explicitly to get the contents after the ":".

Expected return: `["First Name", "John"], ["Last Name", "De Sour"]`

Important because I'll be turning this into a Hash in Ruby.

Comment: What do you want as expected output?

Comment: `(First Name|Last Name): ([A-Za-z ]+?)`  The `?` makes a quantifier non-greedy... it might work.

Comment: I'm converting it to a hash, so ["First Name", "John], ["Last Name", "Doe de Sour"]

Comment: @BaileyS no it won't. Then you will only match the first letter of the names (because that's just enough for a valid match)

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't, there is really no way to do this without using the "Last Name" string as a separator.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you haven't updated your question enough. Your comment on my answer below makes it sound like you won't always have a "last name" field, and that there may (or may not) be some other arbitrary field listed after first name. Is that correct?

Comment: There will always be a "First Name" and "Last Name" field, but I didn't include other fields because getting those two would answer my question for the others.  Other fields are things like "Email" and "Phone".

Comment: Another reason I'm scanning explicitly for first name, etc. is because some email clients wrap a '*' around bold HTML tags.  I'm dealing with emails forwarded from email clients and other web apps.  I strip most of the html tags out manually before scanning with this regex, but it's not bulletproof.

Comment: @Steve If you're guaranteeing that there will always be a first name and a last name, and they'll be in the same order, then the answer I gave below will already work for you. See it in action: http://rubular.com/r/qfA68b8PO5

Comment: Gotcha.  What if there won't always be other fields?  Like an email or phone field?

Comment: @Steve That's a tougher question. Consider making a new question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend turning this into a single regex that captures first name and last name at the same time (in different capture groups).

```
regex = First Name: ([A-Za-z ]+) Last Name: ([A-Za-z ]+)
```

You'll have first name in capture group 1, last name in capture group 2. No chance of confusion with "first name" or "last name" since they've been explicitly called out.

See it in action: http://rubular.com/r/qfA68b8PO5

Comment: I would, but the string won't always be the same so I need to do a search for First Name and get the contents immediately after (same with Last Name).  Unless I'm just overthinking it?  The string will be derived from the body of an email.

Comment: @Steve You should add that information to your question, that changes the answer

Comment: Gotcha will do; must be why I'm getting all the downvotes.  :/

Comment: Since OP wants to turn it into a hash, using [capture labels](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Capturing) seems ideal. Also `[[:alpha:]]` has better semantics than `[A-Za-z]` in an i18n world. `%r{First Name: (?<firstname>[[:alpha:] ]+) Last Name: (?<lastname>[[:alpha:] ]+)}`

Answer (score 0):

This returns a hash from an example string:

```
string  = "First Name: John Last Name: Doe"
string2 = "First Name: John Last Name: Doe de Sour"

Hash[*string.scan(/(First) Name: (.+) (Last) Name: (.+)/).flatten]

=> { "First" => "John", "Last" => "Doe" }

Hash[*string2.scan(/(First) Name: (.+) (Last) Name: (.+)/).flatten]
=> {
    "First" => "John",
     "Last" => "Doe de Sour"
}
```

And this returns an array of hashes from multiple strings:

```
[string, string2].map{ |s| Hash[*s.scan(/(First) Name: (.+) (Last) Name: (.+)/).flatten] }
=> [
    [0] {
        "First" => "John",
         "Last" => "Doe"
    },
    [1] {
        "First" => "John",
         "Last" => "Doe de Sour"
    }
]
```